# Play Framework dependency custom module remote repository authentication

Tags: authentication, module, playframework, dependencies, remote-access

I am trying to set up a custom module reference in the dependency file of the application.

However I need a remote URL to be refered as the artifact.

But I am unable to

```
i.firstly get the dependencies to be resolved from the URL say if it doesn't need any sort of authentication. Please explain me each of the parts to be defined in the dependency.yml while adding custom module

ii. secondly I am unable to find a way to set the authentication credentials for the above repository while it will be downloaded.
```

I am really new to play framework. Can someone please help me with the above.

I am using Play 1.2.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which module do you want to add? Have you really read the documentation on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/dependency?

Comment: Schleichardt,

Yes I did read this.But there is not mention of authentication through dependency.yml.

I am searching for some kind of repository authentication on a download of a custom module from secured repository. Although recently I came across the ivy file implementation stuff... Not quite how to implement it but probably that could be one way of doing somewhat like this in play 1.2.4.

Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. Hopefully this comment can benefit others who are still searching for the answer.

Play frameworks uses Ivy under the hood and you can configure authentication info through `.ivy2/ivysettings.xml` under your home directory. See [Play Framework Document](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/dependency)

To quote from the website

```
<!-- .ivy2/ivysettings.xml -->
<ivysettings>
  <credentials host="maven-repo.xxx"
               realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
               username="user" 
               passwd="reallygreatpassword"/>
</ivysettings>
```

Then modify `conf/dependencies.yml` of your application to point to the custom repo.

```
require:
    - mygroupid -> myartifactid version

repositories:
    - myreponame:
        type: http
        artifact: "url to the repo"
        contains:
            - mygroupid -> *
```